# How to add ImageJ plugin in eclipse?

Tags: java, imagej

Please explain how to add ImageJ plugin in eclipse ?
I download the `ij150-linux64-java8.zip`.

I have linux on my PC and I don't know hot to configure eclipse to support ImageJ plugin.

And if you have a simply code example please share it with me :D

Is necessary to install another library or another plugins?

Please share with me link for download correct version for ImageJ and another plugin if is necessary;

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All [ImageJ components](https://github.com/imagej/) are [Maven](http://imagej.net/Maven) projects. You can simply import them using *File > Import...*, then *Maven > Existing Maven Projects*.

Also, if you only want to develop (or contribute to) a plugin, it is **not** necessary to import the ImageJ source code, as Maven will take care of managing your dependencies. See the [`example-imagej-command`](https://github.com/imagej/example-imagej-command) and [`example-legacy-plugin`](https://github.com/imagej/example-legacy-plugin) projects on github for starting points to develop a new plugin.

For detailed documentation, please refer to the [ImageJ wiki page on Eclipse](http://imagej.net/Developing_ImageJ_in_Eclipse).

If you have more ImageJ-related questions, I recommend asking on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/).